# Correct usage of "In wait"

Tags: verbs, sentence, syntactic-analysis

Would this be a good usage of "in wait"?

> And a large user base in wait for their SDK.

or

> And a large user base-in-waiting for their SDK.

---

Wanted to re-write

> And a large user base waiting for their SDK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is SDK? It could be relevant.

We normally use "in wait" within the idiom "lying in wait" - meaning waiting ready to pounce unexpectedly on someone or something. Soldiers "lie in wait" for their enemy to appear, security staff "lie in wait" for intruders.

If SDK is some kind of system that is expected to be installed the best term would be ***in readiness*** i.e. *And a large user base, in readiness for their SDK*.

Another possibility would be ***awaiting*** i.e  *And a large user base awaiting their SDK*.